# Contain Rotation problem , i need solution in javascript

Tags: javascript

Write a function containRotations that accepts a string str and an array with strings arr.

Return true if all rotations of str are included in arr, otherwise return false.

Consider following:

There are no rotations of str === '' in any arr, return true for this case;
The function must be case-sensitive;
String str can contain letters, spaces, numbers and special symbols.

```js
containRotations('', []) === true
containRotations('abc', []) === false
containRotations('stR!ng', ['stR!ng', 'gstR!n', 'ngstR!', '!ngstR', 'R!ngst', 'TwshnUh', 'tR!ngs']) === true
containRotations('Word', ['Word', 'dWor', 'rdoW', 'DroW', 'rrWd']) === false // all rotations of 'Word' are ['Word', 'ordW', 'rdWo', 'dWor']
```

I need the solution fast

Comment: Please could you attempt this yourself and include your attempt in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function should do the job:

```js
const containRotations=(word,arr)=>word.length&&!arr.length?false:arr.every(w=>w.length==word.length&&(word+word).includes(w));

[['', []],['abc', []],['stR!ng', ['stR!ng', 'gstR!n', 'ngstR!', '!ngstR', 'R!ngst', 'tR!ngs']],['Word', ['Word', 'dWor', 'rdoW', 'DroW', 'rrdW']]]. forEach (([w,a])=>
  console.log(w,containRotations(w,a)));
```

I removed the element `'TwshnUh'` from the third array, as otherwise the result for that test case would (and should!) be `false`.